# Forward NTLM authentication to corporate proxy from local proxy server

Tags: windows, proxy

I have a Python script which is supposed to access various web API's from our server out through to the internet. The issue is that Python support from what I've seen is quite poor when it comes to supporting  NTLM authentication. This causes our corporate proxy server to always return HTTP code 407. My initial idea was to set up a local proxy server using IIS and the Application Request Routing module, which would forward all requests to our corporate proxy while handling the NTLM authentication. Issue with that approach is that it doesn't appear to be forwarding my NTLM credentials, which the current user is running the Python script from.

Will this approach work? If so, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you taken a look at these?

[NTLM Authorization Proxy Server](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/)

[Python NTLM](https://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/)

Answer (score 14):

Might be a bit late but wanted to mention this nonetheless. No doubt having NTLM support in your script would be great but that would add complexity for no big returns. Might be best to use NTLMAps, Cntlm or Px.

NTLMAps and Cntlm are proxies that do the NTLM auth as an intermediary proxy. However, they both require the user/pass since they are mostly targeted towards Linux users. I historically used these tools on Windows but was annoyed by the same requirement of having to provide the credentials to them and update every time my password changed.

As a result, I've authored [Px for Windows](https://github.com/genotrance/px) which is an HTTP proxy like the above two, but uses SSPI to manage the required authentication with the corporate proxy. All you need to configure is the proxy server and port.

For developing your own apps, the code should also help figure out how to do this within Python and perhaps other languages which have access to SSPI. But you'd rather isolate the NTLM mess and not meddle with it.

Comment: underappreciated post.

Comment: This is in fact by far the best solution out of anything else I've found. Thank you very much for the tool!

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a really old question, but all the answers I have seen require you to enter your NTLM credentials into some sort of python NTLM proxy handling code.  These proxies are also prone to be buggy, in my experience.  I created a solution for Windows, which automatically will detect corporate proxy system configurations and also automatically perform NTLM authentication with the current user's credentials.  This solution uses pywin32 and COM calls.  It isn't pretty, but it works well, so I wanted to pass it along in case it helps someone else.

In the example, I show how to do a POST, but other types of requests should be easy to figure out from this code:

```
import win32com.client

try:
    import _winreg as winreg
except:
    import winreg

class HTTP:
    proxy = ""
    isProxy = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.get_proxy()

    def get_proxy(self):
        oReg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
        oKey = winreg.OpenKey(oReg, r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings')
        dwValue = winreg.QueryValueEx(oKey, 'ProxyEnable')

        if dwValue[0] == 1:
            oKey = winreg.OpenKey(oReg, r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings')
            dwValue = winreg.QueryValueEx(oKey, 'ProxyServer')[0]
            self.isProxy = True
            self.proxy = dwValue

    def url_post(self, url, formData):
        httpCOM = win32com.client.Dispatch('Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0')

        if self.isProxy:
            httpCOM.setProxy(2, self.proxy, '<local>')

        httpCOM.setOption(2, 13056)
        httpCOM.Open('POST', url, False)
        httpCOM.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        httpCOM.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'whatever you want')

        httpCOM.send(formData)

        return httpCOM.responseText

http = HTTP()

print(http.url_post('http://ipecho.net/', 'test=1'))
```

Comment: No way! This is awesome. You're right in saying that most proxies are buggy. We're currently using Ctnlm, which is working fairly well for the most part.  Only issue we're seeing is the Cntlm Windows service will randomly stops when it gets hammered from requests.

Comment: Awesome! 3 and a half years later and this has saved me! Anyway to tie this in with the request library?